# Cool html reports for Junit

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, report

I'm looking for some cool report generators from Junit results, I used maven surefire but it's so poor, I need charts graphs and so on.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific, what "cool" reports are. What data should be displayed in which way?

Answer (score 2):

You could run your builds with Jenkins ([www.jenkins-ci.org](http://www.jenkins-ci.org)). Jenkins is easy to setup and it creates pretty diagrams and browsable reports from your JUnit results.

Comment: It's my "plan B" :) thx for answer!